# If the tangent at $P(m^2,m^3)$ on the curve $y^2=x^3$ is also the normal to same curve then what is the value of $9m^2$?

Tags: analytic-geometry, tangent-line

> If the tangent at $P(m^2,m^3)$ on the curve $y^2=x^3$ is also the normal to same curve then what is the value of $9m^2$?

My Approach: I considered another parametric point and the parameter is t. So the point is Q(t^2,t^3). Now I equated the slope of normal at Q with the slope of tangent at P and obtained the value of t in terms of m and the value is t=-4/9m and further obtained the answer as 9(m^2)=9

Now what my professor did was that he wrote the equation o tangent at P and satisfied the coordinates of Q in the equation and he obtained a quadratic equation in t. After solving the quadratic for the values of t in terms of m he got the value of t as t=-m/2 and got the answer 9(m^2)=8

So why are we getting different values of t?
Whose approach is wrong? Or are both of us correct and the question will have 2 answers?

Please help

Comment: Your working is correct up to showing $t=-4/(9m)$. Your professor's result that $t=-m/2$ is also correct because, as your professor found, $9m^2=8$ which agrees with both answers.  You don't explain how you got $9m^2=9$ and this is where you must have made a mistake.

Comment: Please show your steps. It's harder to see where you went wrong without them.

Comment: @MichaelCohen and Toby: I found my mistake. I accidently wrote m^2 instead  of m^3 in one of the steps. Thanks

Comment: @HarshalChaware No problem!

Answer (score 1):

You have done a typo mistake. It should be $m^3$ instead of $m^2$. You can also another approach for this question [here](https://www.sarthaks.com/540867/if-the-tangent-at-any-point-p-4m-2-8m-3-of-x-3-y-2-0-is-a-normal-also-the-curve-x-3-y-2-0)